# c++ application quits without error on serial data receive

Tags: c++, serial-port, uart

I am trying to set up serial port communication in a c++ application on Ubuntu 20. I am opening the serial port like this:

```
serialPort = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (serialPort == -1)
{
    perror("FAILED ");
    exit(1);
}

fcntl(serialPort, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(serialPort, F_SETFL, (FNDELAY | FASYNC));

struct termios options;

tcgetattr(serialPort, &options);

cfsetispeed(&options, (speed_t) B115200);
cfsetospeed(&options, (speed_t) B115200);

options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | INPCK | ISTRIP | IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | IGNCR | ICRNL);

options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

tcsetattr(serialPort, TCSANOW, &options);
```

I know the port is open and functional, because when I try to write to it, my other device does receive the data. But every time the other device writes data back, the application quits without an error message. Even when I am in debug mode, the debugger just drops and the application quits. This happens regardless of who sends data first, but it does happen consistently every time data is received. Because of this I can also not check the data using the application, since it exits before I would get the chance. Does anybody know what is going on?

For those interested, here is the code I use to write to the serial port:

```
void MotorBenchmarker::sendMessage(char* message, int size)
{
    write(serialPort, message, size);
}
```

Edit 1:
I am using GDB debugger and I now see that the application is terminated with the following message:

> Program terminated with signal SIGIO, I/O possible.

below which it says:

> The program no longer exists.

Comment: Perhaps a signal? Did you try `gdb`? What about a core dump? You talk about receiving but I don't see any `read` calls in your code.

Comment: I am using gdb to debug the application. And with receiving I mean the moment the data should be received on the device, not when I read it. I see the data on the serial line, and the application quits.

Answer (score 2):

`SIGIO` - I did not notice earlier, you did specify `FASYNC` flag, this means that any incoming data is reported through this signal. Since you are not handling it, the program crashes.

Either remove the flag and use `read` - blocking or non-blocking, or install the handler.

Comment: I removed this flag and now it seems to be working, thank you very much!